# OpenGL only showing white screen visual studio 10

Tags: c++, opengl

Im trying to write code with OpenGL and have a sample code that is simply a cube with different colors on each face and looking at it isometrically. WHen I run it all i get is a white screen and the code works on computers on campus so im guessing its a problem with the openGL installation. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Screenshot of what I see below. I already moved all the glut.h files and .dll and .lib files to their respective locations and i dont get any build errors.

http://imageshack.us/a/img209/3046/whitecube.jpg

Comment: Try updating your graphics card drivers

Comment: What opengl version do you use? Do you have legacy fixed-pipeline or modern shader-based code? If the latter, did you generate and bind vertex arrays?

Comment: Code for drawing the cube?

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085809/why-glclear-doesnt-clear-my-screen

Are you clearing the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a problem with OpenGL, check the version of OpenGL your GPU is using:

```
printf("OpenGL Version:%s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
printf("GLSL Version  :%s\n",glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

Check the minimum version required by the code - it probably says it somewhere in the tutorial. If your computer's behind, update your graphics drivers. If you're using one of two possible graphics cards (like on some laptops), try switching to the nice one from the embedded/default one.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about a tutorial. Also, laptops don't have 2 graphics cards, but a graphics card and a graphics chipset. There is a big difference, because a chipset doesn't usually have it's own dedicated memory.

Comment: @Kevin OP mentioned sample code, which is essentially the same thing as a tutorial. I have updated my answer to say GPU instead of graphics card. However, a quick Google reveals that "laptops don't have 2 graphics cards" is false.

Comment: Fair enough removed the -1, I would however like a link to a laptop with 2 graphics card, for pure learning purposes and not to verify your comment ^^.

Comment: Nevermind, I found some. I never knew you could get SLI/Spitfire laptops 0.o